# Rx.js, Subscribe is called with undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm using Rx.js to stream my results from an AJAX call to multiple units.

But I have encountered issue when there is more than on observer subscribing to MapObserver. When the first subscriber will always get the correct data but the rest will get undefined.

```
this.observable        = new Rx.Subject();

observeMap = this.observable
  .map(createMarker.bind(this));

var s1 = observeMap.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, 1));

var s2 = observeMap.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, 2));
```

[image: Console Logs]
Please advice, Thanks!

Comment: sounds like a possible bug (`share` should not be necessary to prevent this problem).  Can you show an example of where you call `this.observable.onNext`?  And which version of rxjs are you using?  Also show `createMarker()`

Comment: I tested in the newest version (2.5.1) and [**it works**](https://jsfiddle.net/q3hqdtro/) as expected. You probably use some, older buggy version of rxjs. as @brandon wrote: `share` should not be necessary to obtain what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution for my question, in order to share an observable across few subscribers, you can use [share](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) method.

```
this.observable        = new Rx.Subject();

observeMap = this.observable
  .map(createMarker.bind(this))
  .share();

var s1 = observeMap.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, 1));

var s2 = observeMap.subscribe(console.log.bind(console, 2));
```